How to setup Auth0 with Nextjs on DigitalOcean app platform
I perform the development on a laptop. Auth0 works fine displaying the Google auth login page.
I have GitHub integration to replicate the development code from the laptop to the DigitalOcean app platform. When I call login from DigitOcean (https://seahorse-app-ts7rs.ondigitalocean.app), the Google auth login page is not shown.
I have updated the Auth0 application settings to adding  the DigitalOcean site to the allowed callback URLs
http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback, https://seahorse-app-ts7rs.ondigitalocean.app/api/auth/callback

The allowed logout URLs are:
http://localhost:3000, https://seahorse-app-ts7rs.ondigitalocean.app

Looking in the browser network log I can see:
https://seahorse-app-ts7rs.ondigitalocean.app/api/auth/callback?error=access_denied&error_description=Service not found: http://104.248.162.47:3010/<nestJS app name>&state=ey

I believe 104.248.162.47:3010 refers to the app component running the NestJs app.
